# Send key function not work when I try to access china bank WEB page

Tags: python, selenium, autoit

Bank web page is "https://nper.cmbc.com.cn/pweb/static/login.html"
The web page should open with IE and require password control program. and then I can't select password field by webdriver, and can't send any word into password field.
I've try this many way, but still can not work. any idea to make this work?

`driver.find_element_by_id("writeUserId").send_keys(user_id, Keys.TAB)`

this code to locate password field,and I've a code compile by auto it

```
  win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'send_pw.exe', '','',1)
```

the send_pw.exe code as blow

```
  sleep(1000) 
  Send("{a}{a}{1}{4}{7}{2}{5}{8}")
```

cause password element can't be locate directly so I locate from upper and TAB to pass word field, then send key.

Comment: What is the error? Can post your code so we can see it

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id("writeUserId").send_keys(user_id, Keys.TAB)
this code to locate password field,and I've a code compile by auto it 
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'send_pw.exe', '','',1)
the send_pw.exe code as blow
sleep(1000)
Send("{a}{a}{1}{4}{7}{2}{5}{8}")
cause password element can't be locate directly so I locate from upper and TAB to pass word field, then send key.

Comment: Edit to your post please